# How to set value in radio button from bean that is stored in request?

Tags: java, html, jsp, radio-button, el

I have stored all the contact details into the bean from model and returned the bean to Controller Servlet. In controller Servlet I'm storing this bean into request and passing it to JSP. In JSP i want the all the user details to be retained in their respective text boxes. I used Expression Language. Its retaining values finely.

```html
 - ControllerServlet.java:
 
String email=(String)ses.getAttribute("user");
String sl_no2=(String)request.getParameter("sl_no"); 
AddContactBean ab=m.getconDetails(sl_no2,email);
request.setAttribute("condetails", ab);
rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("UpdateContact.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);

 - UpdateContact.jsp:
 //Values of Dod,Ph_no,Tags are retaining well.. But not radio button's.
 <input type="text" name="dob" value="${condetails.dob}${param.dob}">
 <input type="text" name="ph_no" value="${condetails.ph_no}${param.ph_no}">
 <input type="text" name="tags" value="${condetails.tags}${param.tags}">
 // only radio button values not retaining. What is solution??
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"${condetails.gender}${param.gender}">
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"${condetails.gender}${param.gender}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid concatenation for EL here,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"${condetails.gender}${param.gender}">
```

should be ,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male${condetails.gender}${param.gender}">
```

Comment: thank you.. I tried this now, but dint work.. is there any other way

Comment: @user2475091 doesnt work ?  any errors ?  Have you looked at the stacktraces?

Comment: No errors. It simply don't work. It won't retain the previously set value.